# Cypher Neo4j Couldn't load the external resource

Tags: csv, neo4j, load

In a Windows environment, I'm trying to load a .csv file with statement:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///E:/Neo4j/customers.csv" AS row
```

It seems not to work properly and returns:
Couldn't load the external resource at:

> file:/E:/Neo4j/Customers.csv
>   Neo.TransientError.Statement.ExternalResourceFailure

What am I doing wrong? thanks in advance

Answer (score 26):

I was getting this error on Community Edition 3.0.1 on Mac OS X 10.10 
It appears that the LOAD CSV `file:///` looks for files in a predefined directory. One would think that in the argument that one would give the Cypher statement the full path but that is not the case.

The `file:///` - for my situation" meant that neo4j would append the given argument you gave to one that was already predefined and then go look for that combined path
The `file:///` pre-defined directory directory did not exist entirely
`/Users/User/Documents/Neo4j/default.graphdb/import`, in my computers directory structure I was missing the "/import" folder, which was not created at install

To fix on my system, I created an "import" directory, put the file to be read in that directory. I executed the Cypher load statement I ONLY put the name of the file to be read in the file argument i.e.

```
LOAD CSV file:///data.csv
```

this worked for me.

Comment: Have you validated that this would be similar on Windows?

Comment: It's the same on Windows, you just create it in your database's configuration directory in your /Documents/Neo4j dir.

Comment: This was helpful!

Comment: on macos it was reporting the import folder location as `/Users/xxx/Library/Application%20Support/com.Neo4j.Relate/Data/`. Note the `%20`. Took me a few minutes to work out that this is the html code for a blank space and the folder path is actually `/Users/xxx/Library/Application Support/com.Neo4j.Relate/Data/`

Answer (score 15):

It appears to be a security configuration. Here's the original answer I found: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37444571/327004

> You can add the following setting in conf/neo4j.conf in order to bypass this :
>
> `dbms.security.allow_csv_import_from_file_urls=true`

Or change the import directory `dbms.directories.import=import`

Comment: This may not be the correct answer for the specific question (because the paths match in this question, whereas I see "file:/var/lib/neo4j/import/path/to/file") but it solves that very similar "can't find file that is there but not in import dir" issue for me.

Answer (score 7):

You can find the answer in the file

```
"C:\Users\Jack\AppData\Roaming\Neo4j Community Edition\neo4j.conf"
```

(above "dbms.directories.import=import")

For version neo4j-community_windows-x64_3_1_1 you have to comment out this line or you have to create the folder \import (which isn´t created through the installation) and add your file into the folder.

---

There it´s written that due to security reasons they only allow file load from the \Documents\Neo4j\default.graphdb\import folder

After commenting out on # dbms.directories.import=import , you can execute e.g. from

```
LOAD CSV FROM "file:///C:/Users/Jack/Documents/products.csv" AS row
```

---

In neo4j.conf I didn´t have to add/set

```
dbms.security.allow_csv_import_from_file_urls=true
```

Answer (score 4):

On (Arch) Linux + `neo4j-community-3.4.0-alpha09`, edit `$NEO4J_HOME/conf
/neo4j.conf`:

- uncomment or add: `dbms.security.allow_csv_import_from_file_urls=true`
- comment: `#dbms.directories.import=import`

Restart neo4j (in terminal: `neo4j restart`), and reload the Neo4j Browser (`http://localhost:7474/browser/`) if you are using a web browser as your Neo4j interface/GUI.

Then, you should be able to load a csv from outside your  `$NEO4J_HOME/...` directory

E.g.,

`LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///mnt/Vancouver/Programming/data/metabolism/practice/a.csv" AS ...`

where my `$NEO4J_HOME/` is `/mnt/Vancouver/apps/neo4j/neo4j-community-3.4.0-alpha09/`

`LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:/mnt/Vancouver/Programming/data/metabolism/practice/a.csv" AS ...`

also works, but not

`LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file://mnt/Vancouver/Programming/data/metabolism/practice/a.csv" AS...`

or

`LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "/mnt/Vancouver/Programming/data/metabolism/practice/a.csv" AS...`

i.e. use `...file:/...` or `...file:///...`

Answer (score 2):

It's probably an URL issue, try `file:c:/path/to/data.csv`

See my blog posts:

- http://jexp.de/blog/2014/10/load-cvs-with-success/
- http://jexp.de/blog/2014/06/load-csv-into-neo4j-quickly-and-successfully/

Comment: i m using ubuntu and 1 tried running the url on browser. for me, file was there. i even changed the permission for file to check whether the resource load failure is because of file permission or not. Nothing helped

Answer (score 1):

For the ubuntu system, I placed the file in `/usr/lib/neo4j` which helped me solved the issue. On every other location, i tried giving full permissions(777) but the problem remains the same. After going through another stackoverflow post, i realized that the file should be kept in neo4j directory.

Answer (score 1):

In the Neo4j desktop select the database you are using, go to the setting and there you will find the solution... just comment the "dbms.directories.import=import" line

# This setting constrains all `LOAD CSV` import files to be under the `import` directory. Remove or comment it out to

# allow files to be loaded from anywhere in the filesystem; this introduces possible security problems. See the

# `LOAD CSV` section of the manual for details.

dbms.directories.import=import  ### COMMENT THIS LINE

Answer (score 1):

For `macOS Mojave v 10.14.5`

Actually, I had to uncomment `dbms.directories.import=import` from `~/Library/Application Support/Neo4j Desktop/Application/neo4jDatabases/database-e2dd2a9c-d450-4639-861b-1e7e42b56b31/installation-3.5.5/conf/neo4j.conf` and restart the service. Then it worked. All files has to be placed in `import` directory.

Run command `LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'FILE:/<yourCSV>.csv' as l return l`

Answer (score 1):

I am using the Neo4j Desktop and as others have said, the default graph database has a predefined import location. You can find the location by using the UI. If you put the CSV into the `import` directory, then you can use the relative path directly from you `load csv` command

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Neo4j version is 3.1.1, OS is win10.

For me, LOAD CSV would read from **Neo4j_Database_Location/testDB/import/artists.csv**.

At first, I put csv file on the path  F:\code\java\helloworld\artists.csv, and my cypher sentence is

```
LOAD CSV FROM 'file:///F:\\code\\java\\helloworld\\artists.csv' AS line  
CREATE(:Artist {name:line[1],year:toInt(line[2])})
```

Then I get the error message returned as follows:

```
Couldn't load the external resource at: file:/D:/Neo4j/db/testDB/import/code/java/helloworld/artists.csv
```

It means neo4j itself concat the file path.
"D:/Neo4j/db/testDB/import/" is the Neo4j database location, and the "code/java/helloworld/artists.csv" is the csv file location.

For example, I install Neo4j on the path D:\Neo4j\Neo4j CE 3.1.1, and database loaction is D:\Neo4j\db. I put the CSV file on the path D:\Neo4j\db\testDB\import\artist.csv. If you don't have the file folder "import" on the path, you should creat it by yourself and put your file in the folder "import".

Then, put your csv file in the path, and input cyper sentence:

```
LOAD CSV from 'file:///artist.csv' as LINE
CREATE(:Artist {name:line[1],year:toInt(line[2])})
```

In a word, once you put the CSV file in the right path, the problem can be solved.

Related explaination in the [LOAD CSV developer-manal](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/load-csv/)

> If dbms.directories.import is set to the default value import, using the above URLs in LOAD CSV would read from /import/myfile.csv and import/myproject/myfile.csv respectively.
>   If it is set to /data/csv, using the above URLs in LOAD CSV would read from /data/csv/myfile.csv and /data/csv/myproject/myfile.csv respectively.

Answer (score 0):

1. Set the Property "dbms.directories.import=import"
2. Create folder 'import' explicitly at "/Users/User/Documents/Neo4j/default.graphdb/" because pre-defined directory  did not exist entirely
3. place the csv data set here in the import folder
4. then run the code like - LOAD CSV FROM "file:///C:/customers.csv" AS row

In addition after you run the line, you can analyze what is going wrong in the code section to get a better understanding

Answer (score 0):

you put your dataset into the import directory in neo4j-community path.
Then re-run your command.

Answer (score 0):

Add your csv file in the import folder of neo4j installation guide to do this.

1. open neo4j and start graph of ur project
2. then in open folders tab open import folders
3. Copy ur csv file in this folder
4. Copy that part in ur load syntax as file:///C:/neo4j_module_datasets/test.csv since ur neo4j in running
   in C drive

[Snapshot for your reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OZCkd.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Use the following syntax:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///my_collection.csv" AS row CREATE (n:myCollection) SET n = row
```

If you are running a docker then, follow these commands before running above query:

```
docker run \
-p=7474:7474 \
-p=7687:7687 \
-v=$HOME/neo4j/data:/data \
-v=$HOME/neo4j/logs:/logs \
-v=$HOME/local_import_dir:/var/lib/neo4j/import \
neo4j:3.0
```

Then,

```
sudo cp my_collection.csv /home/bajju/local_import_dir/
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the following should solve the LOAD CSV errors (assuming you have dbms.security.allow_csv_import_from_file_urls=true)

1. If using Linux check for the permissions for the file. Change it using chmod 777 file_name.csv
2. Check if the file format/format for the contents within the file is correct.

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way (be ware of security) is to serve you directory over http and use the http import

- in the command line go the folder where csv files are lcoated
- run the following depending on your python env.

Python 2
$ python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000
Python 3
$ python3 -m http.server 8000
- Now you can load your files from your local host 
LOAD CSV FROM 'http://localhost:8000/mycsvfile.csv' AS row
return row
- you can actually expose files on one host and load them where your DB is running by exposing the folder and replacing localhost with your IP