# Neo4j 3.0.3 Importing CSV

Tags: import, neo4j

I'm currently on my Mac and I can't seem import csv files. I have tried putting the csv file in my graphdb and use `LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///b.csv" AS B` as well as importing it from its original location with `LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///Users/username/Desktop/folder/b.csv" AS B`. The main error I receive is "Couldn't load the external resource at:" It seems I have an import in front of my file every time, for example when I do `LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///b.csv" AS B`the location is given as "file:/Users/allenlu/Documents/Neo4j/default.graphdb3/import/b.csv" I'm not sure how to get rid of the import, or how to use it to actually import my csv.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [neo4j LOAD CSV returns Couldn't Load external resource - neo4j lost in directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37444448/neo4j-load-csv-returns-couldnt-load-external-resource-neo4j-lost-in-directory)

Answer (score 1):

Now, csv files must be in NEO_HOME/import and your file:// url must be relative to this folder.