# Neo4j - Couldn't load the external resource at: file:

Tags: csv, neo4j

I am using ubuntu 14.04 and trying to import csv file but getting following error - `Couldn't load the external resource at: file:/usr/share/neo4j/import/orders.csv` 
My query is -

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///orders.csv" AS row
MATCH (order:Order {orderId: row.SalesOrderID})
MATCH (product:Product {productId: row.ProductID})
MERGE (order)-[pu:PRODUCT]->(product)
ON CREATE SET pu.unitPrice = toFloat(row.UnitPrice), pu.quantity = toFloat(row.OrderQty);
```

I have placed csv files at `/var/lib/neo4j/import` and also changed permission `sudo chmod 777 -R /var/lib/neo4j/import` but still not working.
file permissions are as -

```
sachin@sachin:/var/lib/neo4j$ ls -la
total 28
drwxr-xr-x  7 neo4j adm     4096 Aug 31 10:10 .
drwxr-xr-x 76 root  root    4096 Aug 30 19:33 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 neo4j nogroup 4096 Aug 31 10:10 certificates
drwxr-xr-x  4 neo4j adm     4096 Aug 31 10:10 data
drwxrwxrwx  2 neo4j adm     4096 Aug 31 11:16 import
drwxr-xr-x  2 neo4j nogroup 4096 Aug 31 10:10 .oracle_jre_usage
drwxr-xr-x  2 neo4j adm     4096 Jul 28 09:19 plugins
```

Please help!!! Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37444448/neo4j-load-csv-returns-couldnt-load-external-resource-neo4j-lost-in-directory/37854741?noredirect=1#comment65074172_37854741 you can try to set it other folder

Comment: @ran , thanks for your response , can you please let me know where is conf/neo4j.conf ? I am newbie in neo4j

Comment: when i load my neo4j (windows ) there is options button it show u the path

Comment: try under \Neo4j Community Edition\neo4j.conf

Comment: okay I got it under '/etc/neo4j' , let me try your suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay , I've resolved it by creating new directory **import** under **/usr/share/neo4j** , place csv files in this directory and set its permission to 777.

**Explanation** Since my error was `Couldn't load the external resource at: file:/usr/share/neo4j/import/orders.csv` and I placed my csv files at `/var/lib/neo4j/import`. Hope it will help others,Thanks.