# Neo.ClientError.Statement.ExternalResourceFailed on Windows

Tags: windows, csv, neo4j, load

I just install neo4j 3.2.3 on my windows notebook and I try to load csv file.

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///test.csv' AS line
WITH toUpper(line.TEST_NAME) AS TEST_NAME
CREATE(TEST);
```

I got the following error:

```
Neo.ClientError.Statement.ExternalResourceFailed: Couldn't load the external resource at: file:/C:/Users/*****/Documents/Neo4j/default.graphdb/import/test.csv
```

I cannot locate the neo4j.conf  or propriety files in the  *default.graphdb* directories.

can someone help?

---

I'm on windows 10 neo4j 3.2.3.
I can load from url. but with the same file format, I failed to load from local.

```
LOAD CSV FROM "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/jexp/d788e117129c3730a042/raw/a147631215456d86a77edc7ec08c128b9ef05e3b/people_leading_empty.csv"
AS line
WITH line LIMIT 4
RETURN line
```

successful

with the same file save as .../Neo4j/default.graphdb/import/test1.csv

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///test1.csv" AS line 
WITH line LIMIT 4 
RETURN line
```

I got error:

```
Neo.ClientError.Statement.ExternalResourceFailed: Couldn't load the external resource at: file:/C:/Users/....../Documents/Neo4j/default.graphdb/import/test.csv
```

From the error message, it can locate the file. But cannot perform the LOAD from local.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cypher Neo4j Couldn't load the external resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28398778/cypher-neo4j-couldnt-load-the-external-resource)

Comment: I can load from url,  but cannot load from local with the same file.

Answer (score 0):

> I cannot locate the `neo4j.conf` or propriety files in the
>   default.graphdb directories.

According to the [Neo4j docs](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/configuration/file-locations/#file-locations), the `neo4j.conf` file is located in the directory `<neo4j-home>\conf\neo4j.conf` for zip packages and `%APPDATA%\Neo4j Community Edition\neo4j.conf` for desktop installation.

You should locate the configuration file and set the following line.

```
dbms.security.allow_csv_import_from_file_urls=true
```

Answer (score 0):

The LOAD CSV operation in Neo4j can only load the UTF-8 format files, try to change the import file's format to UTF-8(save the .csv file as .csv(utf-8) type).